# How to implement and unit test a lock in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, locking

I have a method that needs to perform some operations atomically, and also no two calls to this method should be executed simultaneously. Here is my attempt to implement a simple lock (`SomeClass` is registered as a singleton):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private bool isRunning;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        if (this.isRunning)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            this.isRunning = true;
            // do some work that has to be done atomically and takes some time
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            this.isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

First of all is this correct?
Secondly, how can I unit test this?

Comment: is this supposed to work in a multithreaded system?  because that isn't a lock

Comment: @KeithNicholas thanks for pointing that out, no this is a single-threaded application.

Comment: then how on earth can you get two calls to DoWork?  Unless something in DoWork calls DoWork? in which case, why is it calling DoWork?

Comment: @KeithNicholas I have a scheduled background task that calls this method every few mins

Comment: so this is multi threaded? in which case, back at the problem that you don't actually have a lock

Comment: @KeithNicholas what is the problem with this approach? bc when I test this code, I can see that it acts like a lock and no two calls to this method are being executed. But I am new to background tasks and locks, I'm probably missing something fundamental here .. could you please provide me some resources so I could get a better understanding what is the correct approach?

Comment: ok, I'll try and answer it with a regular C# lock

Comment: sorry, got sidetracked

Comment: @KeithNicholas no worries, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that your thread can be interrupted at any point, many times your code might work, in fact if the actual work is significant, your code will work a very high percentage of the time, however it's not robust, so having a look at your code, if `this.isRunning == false`.... and two threads try and call DoWork....

```
           if (this.isRunning)
                {
                    return;
                }
    // first thread gets to here, and gets context switched, then that means 
    // second thread will get to here also as isRunning is still false,
    //  but now we have two threads in this piece of code which is what we wanted to avoid.

                try
                {
// first and second thread will come here now....
                    this.isRunning = true;
// and both will go on to do work....
```

The framework provides standard Thread primitives that will stop that from happening.  So, I've separated the critical section out into a separate class (JustOne) so you can test it independently of your work code.

```
public class JustOne
{
    private Object _lock = new Object();

    public bool Do(Action action)
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(_lock, ref lockTaken);
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                action();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then your class looks like

```
public class SomeClass
 {
     private readonly JustOne _work;
     public SomeClass()
     {
         _work = new JustOne();
     }

     public bool DoWork()
     {
         return _work.Do(() =>
         {
             // actual work
         });
     }

 }
```

now you can test JustOne with something like

```
        public void TestLock()
        {
            var first = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var second = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var work = new JustOne();
            var t = Task.Run(() => work.Do(() =>
            {
                first.Set();
                second.WaitOne();
            }));
            first.WaitOne();
            Assert.False(work.Do(() => { }));
            second.Set();
            t.Wait();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, could you also please explain briefly why my approach is wrong in your answer? I think I also should change the question to something like “how to implement and unit test a lock in c#”

Comment: why not reduce boiler plate code and use `lock(lockingObject) { DoWork(); }` instead?

Comment: @MikeLimaSierra  yes, but that is slightly different that what was asked for, that will serialize the work, each thing will block till ready.     The version I have here is if it can't get the critical section, it doesn't block but returns it couldn't do it.